# What are the monsters shown in Kong: Skull Island post credit scenes?

Tags: reference, credits, kong-skull-island, monsterverse

In the post-credit scenes of **Kong: Skull Island** it shows some monsters. Who are these monsters and what powers do they have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you might already know by now it was set up for [MonsterVerse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonsterVerse) franchise based on Japanese [Kaiju](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiju) monsters. And there are a lot of apparently [17](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101307/what-are-the-names-of-the-17-titans). The four we see are:

[image][image][image][image]

Godzilla, Rodan, Mothra and Ghidorah.

[image]

**Godzilla** and his powers have been already displayed in [Godzilla (2014 film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_(2014_film)), still to reiterate:

- Amphibious Nature
- Atomic Breath
- Durability
- Energy Absorption and Projection
- Intelligence
- Stong Senses
- Speed and Agility
- Stamina
- Thermonuclear Pulses
- Radiation Stream
- Rattling
- Regeneration
- Speed and Agility
- Strength and Combat

Refer [wiki](https://godzilla.fandom.com/wiki/Godzilla_(MonsterVerse)) for the details about these powers and when he uses it.

[image]

**Rodan**

He appeared in *Godzilla: King of the Monsters* and in a prominent role, his powers are:

- Bio-volcanic Nature
- Cyclonic Drift Streams
- Durability
- Flight
- Speed and Agility
- Strength and Combat

[image]

Refer [wiki](https://godzilla.fandom.com/wiki/Rodan_(MonsterVerse)) for more.

**Mothra**

Referred as Queen of the monster also appeared in *Godzilla: King of the Monsters*, her powers are:

- Abdominal Stinger
- Bioluminescence
- Durability
- Energy Dispersal
- Flight
- Raptorial Forelimbs
- Silk Attack
- Speed and Agility
- Strength and Combat

[image]

**King Ghidorah**

He was the main antagonist in *Godzilla: King of the Monsters* and his powers are:

- Alpha Call
- Durability
- Energy Drain
- Flight
- Gravity Beams
- Hurricane Winds
- Intelligence
- Oxygen Independency

Refer [wiki](https://godzilla.fandom.com/wiki/King_Ghidorah_(MonsterVerse)) for more.

Answer (score 7):

Based on this [source](http://www.denofgeek.com/us/movies/kong-skull-island/262706/kong-skull-island-ending-explained), the monsters are:

1. **[Rodan](http://godzilla.wikia.com/wiki/Rodan)**

   [image: Thy mighty Rodan]

   > Rodan. This big creature is loosely supposed to be a variation of Pteranodon, albeit larger and standing more upright. Rodan first appeared in 1956’s Rodan, a Toho film about a flying beast that can breathe poisonous gas from its mouth and has been slumbering beneath the mines of the earth for hundreds of millions of years until a nuclear blast wakes him. He flies, he bites, and he’s all around a tough customer.
2. **[Mothra](http://godzilla.wikia.com/wiki/Mothra_vs._Godzilla)**

   [image: A giant butterfly...]

   > Mothra is generally depicted as a force for good in Japanese films, first appearing in 1961’s Mothra. She hails from a magical Japanese island where she is worshipped by priestesses and is often accompanied by two fairies, twin young women, who speak on Mothra’s behalf. She’s also a giant moth with peacock markings. But that part’s pretty obvious…
3. **[Ghidorah](http://godzilla.wikia.com/wiki/Ghidorah,_the_Three-Headed_Monster)**

   [image: 3-headed dragon!]

   > This dude first appeared in 1964’s Ghidorah, the Three-Headed Monster. The creature has had multiple origins, including being an alien and a genetic freak from the future, but either way he is a three-headed dragon and he means business.

These guys are all part of the old Godzilla [**Showa-verse**](http://godzilla.wikia.com/wiki/Showa_era) and basing on the [premise of Godzilla: King of Monsters film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla:_King_of_the_Monsters_(2019_film)#Premise), these monsters will be introduced in that movie as part of the [**MonsterVerse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla:_King_of_the_Monsters_(2019_film)#Premise) branding.

Comment: Are they gonna fight godzilla or friendly forces?

Comment: Godzilla went 1-on-1 with these guys in the old movies and considering the new movies pay homage to them, we can hopefully expect a huge showdown... :D

Comment: @Vishwa they made a franchise out of this films called [MonsterVerse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonsterVerse) and if all thinsg go well moneywise then they will fight each other sooner or later

Comment: And based on the Godzilla: King of the Monsters synopsis, Godzilla will indeed fight them all! :D Will add to the answer

Comment: @NikhilEshvar I thought new reboot has no connection with old movies, If it's gonna be huge showdown as that phrase means, count me in :)

Comment: @AnkitSharma that's very much interesting.. thanks for the pointers

Comment: @codeczar not seen kong film

Comment: @NikhilEshvar please update the answer according to the new movie

Comment: @codeczar I will see if I get time later, not sure.