# What are the names of the 17 Titans?

Tags: monsterverse, godzilla-king-of-monsters

I was hoping to see more of them but I guess the CGI budget was reached. So there's Godzilla, King Ghidorah, Monthra, Rodan, Kong, Mammoth monster, Spidercrab monster, another Muto and Turtle monster. Who are the others?

Answer (score 5):

According to [wikizilla](https://godzilla.fandom.com/wiki/Godzilla:_King_of_the_Monsters)

There's 18 Titans in total, including Godzilla.

- Godzilla
- Mothra
- Rodan
- Ghidorah
- MUTO
- Behemoth
- Scylla
- Mokele-Mbembe
- Baphomet
- Tiamat
- Typhoon
- Abaddon
- Leviathan
- Sargon
- Bunyip
- Methuselah
- Kong

Comment: Why did the titans follow King Ghidorah's instructions without a fight when Godzilla and Mothra just ignored him?

Comment: @EugeneNero Please as that as a question, not as a comment.

Comment: Although not seen as there's a Monarch site in Loch Ness one Titan must be Nessie

Answer (score -2):

You forgot a few:

- Destoroyah (just another monster but kinda popular)
- Space Godzilla (I think it is what pushed Gidhorah off its planet)
- Biollante (another monster semi-popular)
- Battra (Mothra's brother)
- Megaguirus (another titan)
- Hedorah (the Fog Monster)
- Megalon (one of the first)
- Monster X (a stronger one)

There are more but those are the ones I saw you forgot. There are more than 17, a lot more.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Godzilla lore, but from some quick Googling, those haven't all made their way into the recent franchise, have they? I think the 17 asked about here were limited to said franchise; correct me (or [edit] the answer to clarify) if I'm missing something.

Comment: Well space Godzilla, monster x  are from space, and Biollante and Destroah are found much later, i could see then bring back a few but not all of them

Comment: They did use the oxygen destroyer and that is what created Destroyha so he might enter the franchise he was the last of the Heisei Godzilla movies.